# How do you pass a Timestamp as a Web API parameter?

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, timestamp

I have what I think is a fairly common task.  I have a REST API that provides access to an **Alert** resource.  When I query for Alerts, I want only the most recent ones, I don't want the entire universe (except for the first call I make).  The natural candidate for the 'freshness' criteria is the **Timestamp** datatype in SQL.  So, the first call I want to do something like this:

```
https://localhost/api/alerts
```

Which returns everything.  My code will then scan the returned results, find the maximum Timestamp, and the next call will look like this:

```
https://localhost/api/alerts/<maximumTimestamp>
```

The issue is: what datatype should I use to pass the **Timestamp**?  I don't like using a long because it seems like an interpretation of the byte[8] field that could get me into trouble on some machines.  I thought about encoding it as a Base64 string, but that seems like a lot of work back and fourth (although, in a URL, everything is going to be encoded).

Has anyone else tried to deal with passing timestamps to reduce the size of the REST API result sets?

Comment: can you explain what problem with you when use Epoch time (long) for Timestamp? I used Epoch time for this case and no problem?

Comment: Sometimes it might be useful to be able to enter the URL manually, so I suggest using a string as a parameter (C# format could be `yyyyMMddHHmmss`) and parse that. The URL would look like this: `https://localhost/api/alerts/20190301103625`. If you want to, you can also add milliseconds.